# How to write an xpath for related attribute

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm looking to obtain the surname of the author as designated in the following XML tree:

```
...
<contrib contrib-type="author">
          <name>
            <surname>Obama</surname>
            <given-names>Barack</given-names>
          </name>
          <xref rid="aff1" ref-type="aff"/>
          <xref ref-type="corresp" rid="cor1">*</xref>
        </contrib>
```

I don't know if this is possible but can I define the Xpath

```
//xref[@ref-type="corresp"]
```

and then get the surname value?

```
/name/surname
```

I've never written an xpath value before and in the W3schools tutorial / playing around with a generator I can only work out how to query sub-levels, e.g. getting contrib-type="author" then selecting the associated surname(s). Here what I want is on 'the same level' I think, i.e. below `<contrib>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the `surname` starting from the `xref[@ref-type="corresp"]` node, you can navigate to their parent using `..` (will take you to the related `contrib`) and then go down again up to the `surname` using `name/surname`:

```
//xref[@ref-type="corresp"]/../name/surname
```